# What is the 'right' way to resize a SymbolIcon?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to be able to define a style and set the style on the icon (or on the button that holds the icon).

Setting the button h/w doesn't enlarge the symbol and adding a Viewbox works, but I can't figure out how to set that from a style.

```
<Button x:Name="ZoomInButton" Style="{ThemeResource HeaderButtonStyle}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Click="ZoomInButton_Click">
   <SymbolIcon Symbol="ZoomIn" />
</Button>
```

Any help very much appreciated! Seems so easy, but I'm stumped!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In UWP apps, the standard glyphs are provided by the Segoe MDL2 Assets font, you can directly use a `TextBlock` with `FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"`, so you can change the icon's size by setting the `FontSize` of the `TextBlock`.

For example here:

```xml
<Button x:Name="ZoomInButton" Style="{ThemeResource HeaderButtonStyle}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Click="ZoomInButton_Click">
   <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE8A3;" FontSize="30" />
</Button>
```

For more info about this font, you can refer to [Guidelines for Segoe MDL2 icons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font).

Comment: Thanks Grace! I saw this  for Windows 8 but it sure is nicer to be able to use the names!  I can't understand why ms would provide the nice icons without a way to specify size.

Comment: Life. Saver. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `SymbolIcon` or `TextBlock` I suggest [using a `FontIcon` instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font#using-the-icons):

```xml
<Button x:Name="ZoomInButton" Style="{ThemeResource HeaderButtonStyle}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Click="ZoomInButton_Click">
   <FontIcon FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xE8A3;" FontSize="30" />
</Button>
```